# Google Groups: Retrieve list of groups for a user

Tags: google-groups, google-provisioning-api, google-groups-api

Is there an API to get the list of all Google groups a user is part of (of course, with his/her permission) and vice versa (given a Google group, get all users part of that group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Apps Provisioning API lets you [retrieve the current memberships for a Google Apps user](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_all_groups_for_a_member) as well as [list all members of a Google Apps Google Group](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_all_members_of_a_group). However, there is no way to do this for consumer (@gmail.com) Google Accounts and regular (@googlegroups.com) Google Groups.

Comment: Yes. I meant it for Google Apps only. I understand this is possible only with an administrator account (obviously, as the API can also be used to add/delete users). For a non-administrator, could it be possible to just "read" user/group info?

Comment: No, only Google Apps admins can access the Provisioning API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#getting_started

Answer (score 1):

Also it need not be Google Apps Provisioning. They also have gdata Services and retrieve Groups function. For example
if you have an user example@domain.com, then you can use RetrieveGroups(String memberId, bool directOnly) where memberId is the email address and directOnly must be set to True. This works sleek.