# Google SSO: List groups an authenticated user is a member of

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sso

I want to list the groups the current google workspace user is a member of. The reason for this is that I want to manage grafana permissions based on this.

This is easily done with github sso where the equivalent api call is https://api.github.com/user/teams. Is there an equivalent api call for google SSO?

[Google Groups: Retrieve list of groups for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051828/google-groups-retrieve-list-of-groups-for-a-user) is very similar to this - unfortunately it requires multiple api calls and higher permissions.

Comment: The Q&A you're referencing is from 2012, things have changed a bit since then. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list